# React and Node app download zip file from REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a React and Node app and I have a table with download button.
When I click the download button it makes a request to the node app which I want it to make a call to a REST API to download a zip file in the browser.

I managed to download the zip file by linking the REST API url directly from React but my manager told me not to expose the API url and mask it through Node.

I tried different methods that I found on the web but none of them work, just one that downloaded a zip that contained a file that contained base64 of the files probably.

I would like a solution both for React and Node how to download from a REST API.

Thanks

React code:

```
 $("#example tbody").on('click', '#buton123', function() {
   
   
  var 
   id=response.data.mesaje[$(this).closest('tr').index()].id;
 
   article2 = {id2:id} 
   axios.post('http://localhost:3001/descarcare',article2)
   .then((respo 
    nse)=>{
   //How to download zip from node 
   })

   });
```

Node code:

```
app.post('/descarcare', function(req, res) {

var id = req.body.id2;
console.log(id);


axios.get('http://restapi.com/aaa?id=123').then((response)=>{
//Code to download zip from rest api
)}




});
```

Comment: Go with `axios` for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Hello to SO! If I got your query correctly, you want to proxy the request to the (third-party?) API through your Node.js backend? So that the UI only needs to connect to your backend and no other services. Correct? Then you can just use something like axios (as mentioned by @SilvanBregy) to fetch the file from the API whenever e.g. your frontend calls `https://<your-api>/download` and return it as a response to the UI.

Comment: Yes...make request from React to Node and from Node to REST API

Comment: I would like a working code example please

Comment: @RamonS SO is not a free coding service. Please try out some stuff first on your own, let us know where you are stuck (e.g. the error message etc.) and then we will help.

Comment: Create an Express route/endpoint and have that do the work of contacting the API and sending the zip file when React calls it. I'm assuming you already have routes in your existing nodeJS app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pipe a pdf download response from an api (node/express) to a client (react)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037367/how-to-pipe-a-pdf-download-response-from-an-api-node-express-to-a-client-reac)

Comment: Johannes I followed what it says in the link and it downloads a zip ok 1kb and when I try to open it it says its corrupted or it has nothing in it. The correct zip has 8 kb....any other code ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing make api request to your source zip file containing rest api from nodejs and get stream data and then pipe it res. In this way you can get stream data directly to react js application from nodejs application

Answer (score 0):

Check `jszip` and `jszip-utils` libraries available for zipping the content.